# Seeking baptism record for Jacob Reinhart born 1799 at Bietzen, Saarland, Deutschland?

Tags: germany, baptism-records, 1790s

I've recently started researching my family tree. It all started as a college assignment for my son. Currently, I am stuck on a relative, Jacob Reinhart, that was born in Germany in 1799. A birth town I found is Bietzen (ohne Geburten), Saarland, Deutschland. Death was in 1847.  His wife was Mary (Maria) Elizabeth Hane (Haines).

Comment: I've assumed that your specific question will be how to locate this ancestor's baptism record. What is the source of his birth location?

Comment: It was through research on Ancestry.com.

Comment: Was it in a census record, in someone else's tree or from somewhere else?

Comment: Welcom to Genealogy & Family History SE. "(ohne Geburten)" = "without births" -- sounds like part of a description of a collection or microfilm contents, that is, a particular set of records for Bietzen are missing the birth entries. Did you use the phrase "A birth town I found" to indicate that this was a possible match, or are you more certain?

Comment: Is there a way that I can attach the file that has the information I am using?